# Bash script for Cisco Anyconnect VPN (error passing info)

Tags: bash, vpn

I want to automate connection to a work VPN using the terminal / bash script. I have tried a few ways but having troubles with all methods.

I am running this command in the terminal:

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect [ip here]
```

The command prompt appears with the username already filled in. All I need to do is simulate an "ENTER" key to advance to the password prompt, then I want to fill in the password and simulate "ENTER" again.

I have tried various ways to simulate the first "ENTER" but nothing works (reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script)

```
yes
y
echo -ne "\n"
echo -n "\n"
```

It just hangs there with nothing happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against storing your password in plaintext in a script.

Comment: Is there a way to encrypt the file or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing something like :

```
echo -e "\n<password>" | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect [ip here]
```

where "<password>" is your password. Command will look like :

```
echo -e "\nMyPassw0rd" | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect [ip here]
```

Edit : Removed last \n as requested

Comment: So there's progress, but not quite working. It is pressing the enter key, but it appears as if the password is not being entered (it says "Login Failed"). Part of the issue could be that my password has special characters, and it is making the \n something like !\n and that throws an error.

Tried putting spaces around the password and that throws the "login error" rather than the "!\n even not found" error.

Comment: So you gave me the template, and it only required one modification. I just needed to remove the final "\n", and that did the trick! Thank you!